# Has autogamy been observed in any animals?

Tags: zoology, microbiology, reproduction

By my understanding, autogamy, i.e., reproduction that is sexual, but with both gametes contributed by the same individual, is not at all uncommon in the plant kingdom.

Does this also occur anywhere in the animal kingdom?

Comment: @kmm I appreciate the help! But your revision greatly changed the meaning of my question, including cases I wanted to exclude and vice versa.

Comment: Then I suppose I don't really understand your question. What do you mean "animals that have sex with themselves?"

Comment: @kmm is it not adequately elaborated on, explained, in the text body? If not I think the text is what may need further sharpening up!

Comment: Perhaps he means self-fertilization? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autogamy

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are some animals which are known to self-fertilize (although generally not exclusively).  For instance, among invertebrates some [nematodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nematode) are known to use self fertilization, as discussed in [this paper about its evolution](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4126538/).  Among vertebrates, it seems to be very rare, [apparently known only only in a single genus of fish](http://www.pnas.org/content/106/34/14456.full).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're referring to self-pollination. This is a specific subset of the larger category [**autogamy**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autogamy), in which two gametes from the same individual fuse.

It looks like this [has been documented](https://books.google.com/books?id=DRD5ueZKWlMC&pg=PA336&lpg=PA336&dq=animal%20autogamy%20-paramecium&source=bl&ots=_WjRXgnvJm&sig=Lhvj9vFylrU9f6umfagHo_ekPwk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjRh_a4zpHYAhUB-2MKHcSOA-oQ6AEIRTAE#v=onepage&q=animal%20autogamy%20-paramecium&f=false) most completely in [starving *Paramecium*](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/3743667), although [Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/science/self-fertilization) seems to think it is common in invertebrates as well (without a source).

[One source](https://www.nature.com/articles/hdy200886) thinks that plants are the most successful example of autogamy because the development of several pollen tubes simultaneously allows the plant to carefully choose the fertilizing source, enabling it to select for genetic material that can mask the deleterious recessive alleles.